# unable to delete files on joomla install fedora 20

Tags: php, joomla, fedora

I can't get Fedora to allow med to delete installation files or write the configuration.php. I have chmod 777 all files and directories.

chown apache:apache all files.

It will work correctly if I copy the configuration.php to the directory. But then I can't upload templates because the joomla/tmp folder is not writable.

Any ideas how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, change back the file permissions. Do not make everything 777. Files should be 644 and folders should be 755.

The reason why you are not able to edit files or upload anything is due to the folder ownership. This is something that you hosting provider will need to sort out for you.

Comment: It's running on my own server and all folders are owned by apache.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was that SELINUX prevented apache from writing to disc.